# When field1 and field2 are '0' then field3 should be hidden in a row

Tags: excel, rendering, ssrs-2012

I have a scenario that field1, field2 are equal to zero and rendering is excel then the field3 should be hidden.
How to achieve this in SSRS.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: don't know how to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the hidden property to something like

```
=IIF(Fields!field1.Value = 0 
     AND Fields!field2.Value = 0 
     AND Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML"
    )
```

This will return True if all conditions are met to the `Hidden` will equal `True;

Comment: Thank u so but in my case format is a parameter. is it going to work for that also?

Comment: This just tests if the output is being rendered to Excel, it does not matter if you have a parameter setting that or not it will still work.